# Facebook Video Like using custom like button

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-like

I am developing an iPhone application that lists videos posted on logged-in user's wall. I would like to provide an Like button below each video listed. When the user clicks on this Like button, the corresponding video should be liked in Facebook.

The Like button shown in the UI should match the UI theme of my app. I have gone through Facebook plug-in documentation related to Like button. Following is the link with the documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

But, I cannot use this Like button generated using iFrame since I will not be able to customize the look of Like button.

How can I customize my Like button? Or how can I programmatically like a Video URL? I am trying to this since long time. I have seen some iPhone apps already having custom Like button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it using Graph API. New SDK provides support for Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for a nice how-to on styling:
http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/disguising-a-facebook-like-link/

And the specific policy from Facebook is that as long as you are not deceiving the user, the policy team would consider this practice acceptable.